# Overloaded functions, redefinitions, C2371 and C2556 C++

Tags: c++, overloading, redefinition

Ok so I've got 3 files:

definitions.h which contains

```
#ifndef COMPLEX_H 
#define COMPLEX_H 
class Complex
{

char type; //polar or rectangular
double real; //real value 
double imaginary; //imaginary value
double length; //length if polar
double angle; //angle if polar

 public:
//constructors
Complex();
~Complex();
void setLength(double lgth){ length=lgth;}
void setAngle(double agl){ angle=agl;}
double topolar(double rl, double img, double lgth, double agl);
#endif
```

functions.cpp which contains

```
#include "Class definitions.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip> 
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

Complex::topolar(double rl, double img, double lgth, double agl)
{
real=rl;
imaginary=img;  
lgth = sqrt(pow(real,2)+pow(imaginary,2));
agl = atan(imaginary/real);
Complex::setLength(lgth);
Complex::setAngle(agl);

return rl;
return img;
return lgth;
return agl;

}
```

and the main programme contains:

```
#include "Class definitions.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip> 
#include <string.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(){

vector<Complex> v;
Complex *c1;
double a,b,d=0,e=0;
c1=new Complex;
v.push_back(*c1);
v[count].topolar(a,b,d,e);
```

But the I keep getting error C2371: redefinition; different basic types 
and C2556: overloaded function differes only by return type

everything i have found online says to make sure the function.cpp file isnt included in the main but as I haven't made that mistake I'm running out of ideas, especially seeing as all my other functions that are set up in the same way (with seperate definition and declaration) do work.

Any help would be great!
Thanks 
H
x

Comment: what is being redefined? What is the actual content of the error message? Why are you asking about overloading when there is none in the code? Why do you have 4 return statements one after another in the same function? Why do you pass local variables in as parameters to the topolar function? What is the value of `count` in the main function? Where are the closing brackets? Why are you using new to allocate local variables? There are many issues here.

Comment: Is the class declared in definitions.h supposed to be left unclosed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As declared topolar function should return double, but the definition in functions.cpp doesn't says that

```
Complex::topolar(double rl, double img, double lgth, double agl)
{
```

try changing this to

```
double Complex::topolar(double rl, double img, double lgth, double agl)
{
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `topolar` function is defined as returning `double` but the implementation has no return type. I am not sure if this is **the** error, but it certainly is **an** error. You need

```
double Complex::topolar(double rl, double img, double lgth, double agl)
```

in the implementation.

Furthermore, you seem to have many return statements in the implementation. This is also an error. Only the first one will have effect:

```
return rl; // function returns here. The following returns are never reached.
return img;
return lgth;
return agl;
```